# Allow certain urls to be available on HTTP too when redirecting everything to HTTPS

Tags: nginx

Right now, I redirected all the HTTP urls to HTTPS using this code in my nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name domain.com
  listen 80;

  location /asset/ {
    # make files under asset directory (recursively) be available over HTTP too
  }

  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```

How can I make files under asset directory (recursively) be available over HTTP too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        location /asset {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

If you’d like to pass missing files to your app you could do something like:

```
location / {
    location /asset {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

location @app {
    # Add whatever logic you'd like to perform, e.g.:
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass /var/run/fastcgi.sock;
}
```

Comment: Added it, throws 404 on files under `asset` dir

Comment: Yes, if desired (you could also go somewhere else if the file does not exist). Plus it is simply the proper way to create locations (nesting) plus `return` doesn't rewrite, it simply returns (think of rewrite like of a function which is altering a variable by reference and return is simply return).

Comment: I meant its throwing 404 on a file which exists. The same file is accessible on HTTPS.

Comment: Have you changed the `root` directive? Or simply copied all of it?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't have the root directive in this server block. Added it and works now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need /asset to be accessible over HTTP and HTTPS at the same time,

You need something like this:

```
# HTTPS server {} section
# HTTP server {} section 
location !~ ^/asset {
   rewrite (.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a syntax error in it? Caused nginx reload to fail.

Comment: Always execute `nginx -t` before trying to reload or restart, it will give you an error message describing the problem.